# Left outer join with where clause from main table

Tags: sql-server

```
select
   b.d,
   sum(pic_sam)/60 
from
   inter b 
left  join
   sah  
      on d=date  
where
   b.d between '01 May 2016' and '06 May 2016'  
group by
   b.d 
order by
   b.d
```

I have written a sql script like above which is showing data like below

```
2016-05-01   00:00:00.000   NULL
2016-05-02   00:00:00.000   2608.422500
2016-05-03   00:00:00.000   20236.230333
2016-05-04   00:00:00.000   21398.398166
2016-05-05   00:00:00.000   0.000000
2016-05-06   00:00:00.000   0.000000
```

Now I need to put another condition here which is

```
select
   b.d,
   sum(pic_sam)/60 
from
   inter b 
left  join
   sah  a
      on d=date  
where
   b.d between '01 May 2016' and '06 May 2016'  **and a.line_code like 'K%;**
group by
   b.d 
order by
   b.d
```

then data should be display like below but the second script is not working as per below requirement.

```
2016-05-01   00:00:00.000   NULL
2016-05-02   00:00:00.000   500.422500
2016-05-03   00:00:00.000   10000.230333
2016-05-04   00:00:00.000   5000.398166
2016-05-05   00:00:00.000   0.000000
2016-05-06   00:00:00.000   0.000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the right table filter to `ON` condition

```
SELECT b.d,
       Sum(pic_sam) / 60
FROM   inter b
       LEFT JOIN sah a
              ON d = date
                 AND a.line_code LIKE 'K%'
WHERE  b.d BETWEEN '01 May 2016' AND '06 May 2016'
GROUP  BY b.d
ORDER  BY b.d
```

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks  Thanks Thanks  a lot  Mr. Prdp. its working for me.